# Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, gmail-api

I try to send an email via java application. But cant connect to gmail host.
Can somebody pls give me support. It already worked with my Eclipse Oxygen at home but in the enviroment i use at work it is always failing. I would really appreciate your help:)

```
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


    public class SendMail {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            final String username = "myemail@gmail.com";
            final String password = "mypassword";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
              });

            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myemail@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("mysendtoemail@outlook.com"));
                message.setSubject("Testbetreff");
                message.setText("Sehr geehrter Herr gng76u76ihn,"
                    + "\n\n Testnachricht");


                    Transport.send(message);


                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just for more details my exceptions: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 at emailPro.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:53)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;

Comment: There's probably a [firewall preventing you from connecting directly](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug), you may need to [connect through a proxy](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy).  Also, you can simplify your code by [getting rid of the Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).